# how to get export data from oracle to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, oracle

I'm trying to change data from oracle data base to mongodb
the problem is :
my friend give me "file.sql" that have all the tables with data
and I want to get this data and add it to my mongo database
please I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a **No**SQL database, thus the SQL file will not help you.

Ask for CSV files, then you can use the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) tool to import it into your MongoDB. Please note, usually it is a poor design when you migrate from Oracle to MongoDB and move tables to collections one-by-one. Typically in a MongoDB you will have much less collections than you have tables in Oracle.

Comment: can I build the database from the sql file after that get the csv file to import it in mongodb??

Comment: No you cannot. But you don't need to do that either. Collections and databases are automatically created if they do not exist. And "columns" do not exist anyway, i.e. each document can have arbitrary fields.

Comment: thank you friend for the informations that mean a lot to me